# Overcoming Browser difference

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a website, so far I've used mostly HTML, CSS, PHP and some JQuery. My problem is that my code is not displaying the same thing in different browsers especially in Internet Explorer.

Google Chrome, Firefox and Opera seem to be the same but Internet Explorer is different. How do I overcome this? Please help, thanks.

Comment: This is the most vague question I've ever seen. What version of IE? What isn't working? Is it the HTML, CSS, jQuery or PHP? Have you got some example code?

Comment: Your going to have to be more specific if its something that's not working and needs to - otherwise, remember http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com

Comment: Vague?  It's not vague at all (especially to those who do web development) - however, the question is phenomenally broad and better served in the multitude of websites and tomes dedicated to just this purpose.

Comment: Do you have a doctype as the very first line, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`? I'm so bored of suggesting this, but leaving that out is [the most likely reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) that IE would be drastically different from all other browsers.

Comment: Please read [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) in the FAQ page.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of different things you can try to balance out the differences between browsers. One of the the most common things to do tends to be using a CSS reset. This will override default styles that browsers apply automatically to your code.

The HTML syntax you use also plays a large part as some browsers will support elements differently if at all. The same goes for CSS.

If you're just starting out I suggest you look at using something like HTML5 boilerplate:
http://html5boilerplate.com/

Once you've been developing web for a few years you tend to know where issues are going to arise between various browsers and know good alternatives or ways to work around those.

Lately a lot of developers have started adopting the "doesn't have to look the same in all browsers" approach. Which is a fair argument as usability and accessibility is more important than how a site looks. After all websites are for serving content.

Answer (score 0):

Is your HTML valid?  You can check this using the W3C validation service at:

http://validator.w3.org/

If not, then I'm going to suggest something that may sound quite asshole-ish, but will still hold:  Learn HTML.  Many people think they "know" HTML, and that is the reason why the Internet is such a mess.  Learn what is valid and what is not valid and familiarize yourself with the DTD.  Despite the belief, there is in fact a proper way of writing HTML and not writing it such a way will cause problems on various browsers.  Do not use non-standard code.  If it's not in the DTD, don't use it.  HTML should also not contain too much formatting, as this should be handled by your CSS.

Also, if you're planning on using HTML 4.01 as opposed to 5, stick with the strict DTD, not the transistional.

Answer (score -1):

Without you updating this question with more information/examples, I can only assume:

**HTML** is your most likely culprit.

Internet Explorer has a difficult time supporting many browser technologies that most developers take for granted. The classic

```
<!-- [IF IE]>

...<> </>

<![endif]-->
```

**referenced: http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html**

approach is what you'll learn most times, especially in class/book settings.

On the web, however, there is the time old advice:

If the page looks bad, well....that's IE. Chalk up a "V" that it isn't mangled, and focus on your core group (20 & 30-somethings who swear IE to be the devil).

From what I've gathered, unless you're doing some corporate sponsored "must-be-IE" type of project (for reasons involving security protocol appeasement), then consider IE an afterthought, and nothing more.

**EDIT**

Not to be forgotten is the crucial Chinese market. If you're designing a website for a Chinese client, remember that everyone uses IE6 (ripped from pirated version of XP). It is a common exception to the above advice.

Comment: One cannot simply ignore IE because it's a pain to develop for.  IE still holds the majority of the browser share, thus failing to develop for it means potentially alienating many users.  Proper advice would be to develop for more W3C compliant browsers (FF, Chrome, Opera) first, then work on making it look right in IE.  Thankfully, since Microsoft has actively been telling users to abandon IE6, the task of making things look presentable in IE has become much easier.

Comment: @kevinmajor1 was your problem with my answer that I said, "don't focus on developing for IE", or was it that the '[IF IE]' tags are not a good answer? This is of course, assuming you voted my answer down.

Comment: Conditional comments that target IE without any version restriction are downright stupid, indeed. There are plenty of sites using that that display fine in IE8+ yet degrade to IE6-era markup just for the sake of it.

Comment: @Joey The link I posted below the example covers that.